# Align text underneath images in css

Tags: css, image

I'd like to make some sort of a program page for a festival. I want to create a list of images with little text underneath. I don't succeed in placing the text underneath (it always ends up next to the images instead of underneath). Can somebody help?

It should look like this:

> [img1] [img2] [img3]
>
> [text1] [text2] [text3]
>
> [img4] [img5]
>
> [text4] [text5]

... and so on

The size of the images is fixed, so that the rows with only 2 images are the same size as those who have 3.

This is my code in CSS thus far:

For the texts (small and big):

```
.prog_big{width:321px; height:434px; margin-left:30px; font-family: Lucida Sans,Calibri; font-size:16px; float:left; text-align:center} 

.prog_small{width:207px; height:283px; margin-left:30px; font-family: Lucida Sans,Calibri; font-size:16px; float:left;text-align:center}
```

For the images (small and big):

```
.poster_big{width:321px; height:434px; margin-left:30px; float:left} 

.poster_small{width:207px; height:283px; margin-left:30px; float:left}
```

Comment: could you post the relevant html code?

Comment: This is the html code I used:


<img class="poster_small" src=""/>

<img class="poster_small" src=""/>
<img class="poster_small" src=""/>


<p class="prog_small">sometext</p>
<p class="prog_small">sometext</p>
<p class="prog_small">sometext</p>
<br><br>

<img class="poster_big" src=""/>
<img class="poster_big" src=""/>
<br><br>

<p class="prog_big">sometext.</p>
<p class="prog_big">sometext</p>
<br><br>

Answer (score 0):

I don't this this is a css issue really. You can achieve this in HTML with this type of layout

```
<figure>
 <img src="your_Image">
 <figcaption>text here</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: I tried this, but then I lose my CSS layout on the images for some reason.

Comment: you'd have to change css to adjust to the tags

Comment: Okay, I made some more changes, and it appears to work. The images are all underneath each other now, instead of in rows of 3 or 2. How can I fix this?

Comment: put them in different figures I believe I'd have to see your code

Answer (score 0):

Division and image tags are not inline element. Because of this reason they will create a new line in the screen for each of them.

Make them inline, using the css "display:inline-block". They will stand side by side.

```css
div.first-row div, div.second-row div {
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:100%;
}

div.first-row div {
  width: 33.3%;
}

div.second-row div {
  width: 50%;
}

div img {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

p {
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class='first-row'>
  <div>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140?text=image'>
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140?text=image'>
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140?text=image'>
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='second-row'>
  <div>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140?text=image'>
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src='http://via.placeholder.com/140?text=image'>
    <p>Some Text Here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried it but I lose the fixed sizes with this code. How do I make sure the images and pieces of texts stay the same?

Comment: @sadlva I didn't understand the your problem with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

A flexbox solution:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

p {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    <p>Text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100" />
    <p>Text 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60" />
    <p>Text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60" />
    <p>Text 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/60" />
    <p>Text 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```